# Volume of a sphere via circle rotation

Tags: integration, 3d, volume, spheres

Is it possible to obtain volume of a sphere by rotating two-dimensional circle 180 degrees (or half circle 360 degrees)? In instances like calculating volume of cubes and 3d rectangular objects, volume is obtained by multiplying 2d surface by another scalar in the 3rd dimension.

By the same logic, a circle is a 2d entity and its rotation takes place in 3rd dimension. I am not sure what specific method would be suitable but general "intuition" makes sense.

Comment: Your intuition is right. It even extends to higher dimensions. "Volume of a solid of revolution" is the correct calculus topic. I'm sure someone will provide an answer along these lines.

Comment: I had this question in mind long back when I was in primary school.

Comment: Is it possible to integrate a function over [0,2pi] to find the volume of a sphere? The function obviously is not pi * r^2/2. I think integrating dV (which equals to pi*r^2/2) over 2pi should give the result. I am just not sure what the right function should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but, respect to simple translation for cubes or parallelepipedes, we need to "adjust" the evaluation to take into account that the solid is obtained by a rotation with respect to an axes, notably it can be done by [Pappus's centroid theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem#The_second_theorem) which states that

> *the volume V of a solid of revolution generated by rotating a plane figure F about an external axis is equal to the product of the area A of F and the distance d traveled by its geometric centroid*

[image]

Comment: So the area of the rotating plane is 1/2 * pi * r * r. This is rotated a distance of pi * r. So we should have the product of these?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, rotate the function 
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{r^2-(x-r)^2}
$$
about the $x$ axis to find 
$$
\pi\int_0^{2r} f(x)^2\mathrm dx=\pi\left( 2r^3-\frac{2r^3}{3} \right)=\pi\frac{4r^3}{3}
$$
Noting the geometric intuition here: we are summing up the areas of circles (we consider them flat, since their width is an infinitesimal $\mathrm dr$) sweeping out of the page.

Comment: Could you a bit more explain what f(x) does? It is not very obvious at first look.

Comment: Did you try graphing it? Are you familiar with volumes of revolution?

Comment: No. I am not familiar. Yet...